# Microsoft.Teamfoundation.dll with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I had been using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll found in

> "{programfiles}\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0"

with visual studio 2010?

Been working on updating the build templates to TFS 2013 and found that the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll is missing in the

> "{programfiles}\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0"

folder.

Where can I find the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll for TFS 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at this location:

"My observation is, using TFS and VS version 2013 onwards, we no longer need to reference to this assembly where as referencing to assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll is enough. This assembly contains Microsoft.TeamFoundation namespace and all sub-namespaces along with classes that represent general information about Visual Studio Team Foundation Server."

[SOURCE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afbb89f9-2eb3-470b-94f3-f0963e2d230f/cant-find-microsoftteamfoundationdll-with-visual-studio-2013-installation?forum=visualstudiogeneral)